# отличия использования позиционирования и margin

Tags: css, position, margin

С того момента, как я узнал о позиционировании в `css`, для меня является загадкой разница между отступами с помощью `margin`(1) и `top\right\bottom\left`(2).

В моём представлении, эти два атрибута делают одно и то же, и единственное их различие, которое смог найти - это то, что (1) относится к `box-model`, когда (2) - нет.

Так же знаю о применении (2) для "относительности сторон", т.е. вещи вроде:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

И тогда он будет "прибит" к левому верхнему краю.

Вопрос состоит в том, когда какой инструмент использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы понять разницу, вам нужно попробовать поставить больше одного элемента:

```css
.m {
  margin: 10px;
}

.r {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div { height: 30px; width: 30px; border: 1px solid #999; display: inline-block; }
body{ font-size: 0;}
span{ font-size:15px;}
```

```html
<hr><span>без отсупов:</span>
<hr>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<hr><span>margin:</span>
<hr>
<div class="m"></div>
<div class="m"></div>
<div class="m"></div>
<hr> <span>top/left:</span>
<hr>
<div class="r"></div>
<div class="r"></div>
<div class="r"></div>
<hr>
```

Вы видите в примере, что `margin` создает настоящий отступ вокруг каждого элемента, сдвигая соседние.

`top/left` же просто сдвигает элементы вниз и влево, никак не влияя на верстку. Теоретически, `top/left` больше похож на `transform: translate`, с отличием в аппаратном ускорении и относительных еденицах

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда рисовал себе правила - на листике:

`margin (внешний отступ) | padding (внутренний отступ): ↑ → ↓ ←;`

Хорошо запоминается.
Есть случаи, когда `margin` не сможет исправить ситуацию отступа от рамки и текст внутри рамки, будет казаться прилипшим, на помощь придет `padding`, который сделает внутренний отступ от рамки элемента.

Comment: мне запомнилось как news - north east west south